# Matlab: Vectorize the transpose in one step?

Tags: matlab

I would like to use the (:) operator and the transpose at the same time. Is this possible? Basically I would like to do something like

```
output = A'(:)
```

except that this does not work. Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks!

Immo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` operator in this case is shorthand for reshaping the matrix into a vector.  You can work around the limitation of where you use the operator by using the `reshape` function explicitly:

```
octave>  A = [1 2;3 4]
A =

   1   2
   3   4

octave> B=A'
B =

   1   3
   2   4

octave> C=B(:)
C =

   1
   2
   3
   4

octave> D=reshape(A',[],1) #% vectorize transpose in one line
D =

   1
   2
   3
   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
output = reshape( A.', numel(A), 1);

>> A = rand(4,3);
>> output = reshape( A.', numel(A), 1);

A = 

    0.447213   0.046896   0.679087
    0.903294   0.768745   0.651481
    0.701071   0.122534   0.611390
    0.535844   0.478595   0.772810

output =

    0.447213
    0.046896
    0.679087
    0.903294
    0.768745
    0.651481
    0.701071
    0.122534
    0.611390
    0.535844
    0.478595
    0.772810
```

Beware that reshape reads the matrices accessing along columns so you may not need to transpose the matrix A.

Also, remember that the operator `'` is the hermitian operator, namely, conjugated of the transposed, whereas `.'` is simply transposition, which you could also get by transpose(A).

You may want to do everything in a single line without re-typing all every time. One solution is creating a function handles as boop:

```
>> boop = @(x) reshape( transpose(x), numel(x), 1)
>> output = boop(A)

output =

    0.447213
    0.046896
    0.679087
    0.903294
    0.768745
    0.651481
    0.701071
    0.122534
    0.611390
    0.535844
    0.478595
    0.772810
```